# VSTest.Console.exe and .NET 4.5.2

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) I can specify the .NET framework when invoking VSTest on the command line but the only available choices are 3.5, 4.0 or 4.5. How can I force vstest to use 4.5.2 or 4.6 for that matter?

**Edited 3/8/2016**:

Here's an example of a unit test that passes under .NET 4.5.2 but fails under prior versions of the .NET framework:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyUnitTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var originalValue = "\"'#";
    var expectedValue = "%22'%23";

    // Act
    var encodedValue = Uri.EscapeDataString(originalValue);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, encodedValue);
}
```

The reason why the version of the .NET framework is important is because URI encoding logic has changed in .NET 4.5.2 and therefore it's important to be able to control the framework used to run this unit test.

Comment: It just doesn't matter, it can only use the framework version you actually have installed on your machine.  Which surely is 4.6.1 right now.  And perhaps you have 3.5SP1, most programmers have it installed.  The only difference you get when you select 4.0 is a handful of bug fixes that were made in 4.5 that won't be in effect.  Pretty obscure ones, mostly affect WPF code.

Comment: I added example in my question to illustrate why it's important to be able to specify the desired .NET framework

Comment: Hmya, nobody here can help you with that, consider filing a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com.  If you want a 100% guarantee then you'll have to run the test on a machine that has the actual framework version installed that you care about.  Pretty hard to do given that versions before 4.5.2 are no longer supported since Jan 12th of this year.  So this doesn't go wrong on the user's machine either, unless he intentionally chose to not keep his machine updated.  Whether you ought to support such a user when Microsoft won't is, well, you know.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. You say it's hard to use .net 4.5.2 to run unit tests given the fact that prior frameworks are no longer supported??? Maybe my question wasn't clear: I want to ensure 4.5.2 is used to run my unit tests, I am not trying to use a prior version of the framework. The '/Framework' command line parameter allows specifying the desired framework but there doesn't seem to be an option for 4.5.2 Most of our machines have multiple .NET frameworks and I am simply trying to ensure our unit tests are executed with the appropriate version.

Comment: Then you have no use whatsoever for the /Framework argument anyway.   Just check `Environment.Version`.  The secret decoder ring [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Very interesting suggestion. So I should change my unit test to detect the framework and change the expected value accordingly. Something like this:
var expectedValue = IsRecentFramework() ? "%22'%23" : "%22%27%23";